# Invert TimeSpan value in a WinForms application, using a Timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I got a Timer in C# which starts at 00:45 which counts down, when it reaches 0, it counts up.

```
    private TimeSpan mytimer;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mytimer.TotalSeconds <= 0)
        {
            timerCourse = true;
        }

        if (timerCourse)
        {
            mytimer = mytimer.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
        else
        {
            mytimer = mytimer.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }

        labelTimer.Text = mytimer.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }
```

Whether it counts up or down is controlled with the `bool` flag `timerCourse`. Now I would like to realize 60s jumps and am encountering problems.

```
    private void btnPlus60s_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timerCourse)
        {
            mytimer = mytimer.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        }
        else
        {
            mytimer = mytimer.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        }
        labelTimer.Text = mytimer.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }
```

For example, if the timer is counting down and is at 40s ({00:40:00}) and I press the plus 60s button, does the timer have the value {-00:20:00}. So I would have to set the flag to true and invert the value of the timer to {+00:20:00}.

Does anyone know how to invert the value?

Comment: Have you tried doing what you just described? Check whether the new value would exceed the limit and change the flag and variable *before* incrementing?

Comment: What is the Type of that `mytimer`? If it's TimeSpan, then you can just do `mytimer = -mytimer;`

Comment: Yeah its TimeSpan. Okay, i try it.